# as3 stage to jpg byte-array to server side php problems

Tags: php, actionscript-3, jpeg

hi im looking to get a test working. embeding a swf that sends a jpeg of the stage to a php script that saves to my server.  im in deep water here and cant get the following to work...

//----------------------------AS3

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var dot:Sprite = new Sprite()
dot.graphics.beginFill(1)
dot.graphics.drawCircle(550/2,400/2,40)
addChild(dot)

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, saveJPG)

function saveJPG():void{


    var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
    jpgSource.draw(stage);

    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
    var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("jpg_encoder_download.php?name=sketch.jpg");
    jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
    jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
    navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");

}
```

//----------------------- php

```
<?php


if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    // get bytearray
    $jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

    imagejpeg( $jpg , "yes.jpg", 100  );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use AMFPHP to handle situations like this. Check out the remoting section of Josh Strikes main page [here](http://www.joshstrike.com/). Just nest the ByteArray into another array holding any other data you need to identify it or just send it by itself. This way you can either decode it and save it to a folder or just stuff the ByteArray into a database to be used later. As stated above you must make sure to encode the ByteArray first.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to encode the byteArray to Base64 before POSTing it, and then decode that on the server side with PHP. But you don't really say what exactly is not working...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the image conversions from BitMapData to BitMap to Image

```
function createJPG():void{
  var finished1:BitmapData = new BitmapData ( stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true, 0xffffffff );
  finished1.draw( stage );

  // the key part you are missing
  var myImage:Image = new Image();
  myImage.load( new Bitmap(finished1) );
  myImage.content.width = stage.stageWidth;
  myImage.content.height = stage.stageHeight;

  var finished:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, true, 0xffffffff );
  finished.draw(myImage); 
  myImage = null;


  // encode the finished image so we can send the data to the server
  var encoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
  var data:ByteArray = encoder.encode(finished);
  var b64:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder()
  b64.encodeBytes( data )
return b64.toString();
}
```

Have a look at this [link](http://labs.findsubstance.com/2008/04/03/as3-upload-encode-images/) it will explain all you need

Comment: very sorry if i am vague but all this is very helpful. i seem to have fixed the problemshowever when i send the byte array to the php script i dont want it to navigate to a new page because of the nature of the piece here is my code as it stands....

Comment: <?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
 // get bytearray
 $jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
 $filename = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
 $handler = fopen($filename.".jpg", 'w');
 fwrite($handler, $jpg);

 fclose($handler);
}

?>

Comment: var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
 jpgSource.draw(stage);
 
 var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
 var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);
 
 var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
 var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("jpg_encoder_download.php?name=sketch.jpg");
 jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
 jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
 jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
 navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest);

Comment: Try editing your original post and put this code there so it's readable

Comment: I added a link that will help you at the end of my post

Comment: sorry im new to this website and dont understand the formating straightaway. thanks for your patience i found your link very useful, i will update it when i get a chance to edit this @The_asMan